Proof that the evolute is the geometric locus of points of the centers of curvature
I am trying to prove that the evolute is the geometric locus of points of the centers of curvature.
Let r = r(s) be an arc-parametrized curve. The normal line at a point r(s) of the curve is line given by:
$$ r(s) + \lambda N(s) $$
where $\lambda$ is a parameter (that shows how far a point is from r(s)). Every point of the evolute E = E(s) satisfies the condition:
$$ E(s) = r(s) + \lambda(s) N(s) $$.
By differentiating the above equation we get:
$$ \frac{d}{ds} E(s) = r'(s) + \lambda'(s)N(s) + \lambda(s)N'(s) $$
$$ \frac{d}{ds} E(s) = N(s)$$
Because the tangent of the evolute at a point is the same as the normal of the corresponding curve at that point. Also:
$$ N'(s) = -\kappa(s)T(s)$$
So we get
$$ (1 -  \lambda'(s))N(s) + (\lambda(s) \kappa(s) -1)T(s) = 0 $$
Since $N(s)$ and $T(s)$ are orthogonal (they are linearly independent) then:
$$ \lambda'(s) = 1 \quad and \quad   \lambda(s) = \frac{1}{\kappa(s)}$$
Hoever I don't think the first equation makes sense. Can anyone point out the mistake?

What are you taking as the definition of the evolute? I'd argue it being the locus of the centres of curvature is the standard definition.

Ah never mind I think I see what you are assuming. You are defining the evolute as the envelope of the normal lines, yes? In which case you only have that $\frac{d}{ds}E(s)$ agrees with $N(s)$ up to pointwise scale. The calculation then goes through but with $\lambda'(s)$ equal to this unknown scale (although of course you can then calculate it from the other equation)
